# localStorage returning undefined until refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I've noticed a bug, or what I believe to be a bug, in the localStorage which is hard to explain but I'll try.

I'm writing a simple local shopping cart. In order for things to work properly I check if the storage already exists and put an empty array into it if that isn't the case.

However, even after this check localStorage still remains undefined untill the second time I refresh the page. See the code below:

```
const cart = function(name) {
    this.storageNamespace = name;
    this.get = store.get(this.storageNamespace); 
};

cart.prototype.set = function (data) {
    store.set(this.storageNamespace, data);
}

cart.prototype.add = function (item) {
    if (this.get === undefined) {
        store.set(this.storageNamespace, []);
    }
    let cart = this.get;
    if (cart.length !== 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
            if (cart[i].id === item.id) {
                cart[i].ammount = Number(cart[i].ammount) + Number(item.ammount);
                this.set(cart);
                break;
            } else if (i === cart.length - 1) {
                cart.push(item);
                this.set(cart);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
    cart.push(item);
    this.set(cart);
    }
}
```

A few things. Yes, this.get returns undefined, I have tested it from the console. Hence I don't understnad why the code inside of the if statement isn't running. I've put the if statement in several places, including the constructor. Same behaviour everywhere.

It all works fine on the second visit though.

To be clear the code that is doing nothing even though it seems to evaluate to true is:

```
if (this.get === undefined) {
    store.set(this.storageNamespace, []);
}
```

Comment: Since you are using es6 scope variables you may as well do classes. The storage variable, what is it? `localStorage` or `sessisionStorage`

Comment: It is Store.js, V2.

Comment: Then show us the setup for your store.js . And more than anything this might be error in the library rather than the `localStorage` itself.

Comment: Not much to show just added Store before my own file at the end of the body. And I doubt this has anything to do with Store.js since it is a well maintained and often used library. They would have spotted it by now. Also, I've encountered these kind of quirks before working without a wrapper so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const cart = function(name) {
  this.storageNamespace = name;
  this.get = store.get(this.storageNamespace); /* store.get is function 
  call, value be will initialized once instance of this function is created */
};
```

When you create instance of this function for the first time, an object with "get" property - undefined is created, because you don't have any value in localstorage initially.

```
cart.prototype.add = function (item) {
if (this.get === undefined) {
    store.set(this.storageNamespace, []); /* Here, you insert value in 
    localstorage,but object's 'get' property is still undefined,i.e there is 
    value in localstorage but not in this object's property */
   // *** Missed this -> this.get = store.get(this.storageNameSpace)
}
let cart = this.get; /* undefined, hence 'if' is not executed */
if (cart.length !== 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        if (cart[i].id === item.id) {
            cart[i].ammount = Number(cart[i].ammount) + Number(item.ammount);
            this.set(cart);
            break;
        } else if (i === cart.length - 1) {
            cart.push(item);
            this.set(cart);
            break;
        }
    }
 } else {
 cart.push(item); 
 this.set(cart);
 }
}
```

Comment: So by including the if statement in the constructor before I declare the get property it would work?

Comment: this.get = store.get(this.storageNamespace) in your add function, where you check for this.get==undefined

Comment: added statement in answer's comment which you need to add

Comment: Also it would be preferable if instead of "get" and "set", some other names are used for your cart

Comment: I know not ideal to name it after API prototypes.